# Linked list add two numbers

Tags: python, linked-list

Any idea why the summation is returning zero , currently trying to add linked list sum , in leetcode its working fine , however while trying for complete solution it's creating error

Problem from leetcode -
You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

Added couple of examples -

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
Output: [7,0,8]
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

Input: l1 = [0], l2 = [0]
Output: [0]
```

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self , data=0,next=None):
    self.data=data
    self.next=next

class solution:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.head = None

  def insert_at_begining (self,data):
       node = Node(data,self.head)
       self.head = node
    

  def print(self):
      if self.head is None:
        print ("Linked list is empty")
        return
      
      listr = ''
      itr = self.head

      while itr:
        listr += str(itr.data) + "-->"
        itr = itr.next 
      
      print (listr)
    
  def revereList(self):
      prev , curr = None , self.head
      while curr:
        tmp =curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = tmp
      self.head= prev

  
  def merge_sorted_upd(self, llist):
    
        p = self.head 
        q = llist.head
        dummy = Node()
        tail = dummy
    
        while p and q:
            if p.data <= q.data:
                tail.next = p 
                p = p.next
            else:
                tail.next = q
                q = q.next
            tail = tail.next

        if  p:
            tail.next = p 
        if  q:
            tail.next = q 
        return dummy.next

  def lp_add_two_numbers(self,p,q):
     ##first create a dummy node
     prev=None
     dummy = Node()
     cur=dummy
     carry = 0
     l1 = p.head
     l2 = q.head
     while l1 or l2 :
       v1 = l1.data if l1 else 0
       v2 = l2.data if l2 else 0

       val = v1 + v2 + carry
       val = val % 10
       carry = val/10
       
       cur.next = Node(val)
       if self.head is None:
            self.head = cur
       else:
            dummy.next = cur
       dummy=cur
       cur = cur.next
       l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
       l2 = l2.next if l2 else None 
      
     return dummy.next 
   

if __name__=='__main__':
   l1=solution()
   l1.insert_at_begining(4)
   l1.insert_at_begining(2)
   l1.insert_at_begining(1)
   l1.print()
   l2=solution()
   l2.insert_at_begining(7)
   l2.insert_at_begining(6)
   l2.insert_at_begining(5)
   l2.print()
  #  l1.merge_sorted_upd(l2)
  #  l1.print()
   res=solution()
   res.lp_add_two_numbers(l1 , l2)
   res.print()
```

output coming as

```
1-->2-->4-->
5-->6-->7-->
0 6 8.6 1.8599999999999994
```

Comment: `lp_add_two_numbers` does nothing with `self.head`. So `self.head` of `res` is still `None`.

Comment: Although please remember this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks , I have added few examples , I understand it's not doing anything with the head , any pointers how can I return the sum value please

Comment: In addition to _reproducible_, a [mre] needs to also be _minimal_. What [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you done? You should step through your debugger and compare the expected intermediate values to what you expect by calculating them on paper. Then you should be able trace the problem back to its source. Often, the exercise of creating a good MRE will take you much closer to the solution than just adding all of your code to the question. Please modify your question to a more _specific_ by including what you found while debugging. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I have modified the code and getting some result , please check the if else section where included head , however the sum showing float value which I am not getting